# Prevent the creation of a particular file in windows

Tags: windows, file, driver

I am looking forward to stop the creation of a particular file with its name as well as stop the creation of all files in a particular path. 
I did my research and came across 2 methods:
1) Using file screening method in Windows SDK.
2) Using Windows driver kit and using ISR Routines.
I am not sure which one would be more efficient practically, and I have no experience with 2) so I would like some insight or general approach to 2) if that is more efficient.
Thanks!

Comment: I think windows MiniFilter driver would be better choice.

Comment: I have actually forked a sample driver from their github and it runs properly. However, nothing happens when I run it. It doesn't throw any error either. I can't see the driver on my memory however it doesn't give an error while loading either, let alone the other functions. Any possible cause ?

Comment: I am trying this : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/obcallback and there is no "sys" file generated as mentioned there. Also I'm running everything as admin.

Comment: Its not minifilter driver. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff540402(v=vs.96)